# is there another way of saying: "shaky structures"?

Tags: expressions

What expression would an English teacher use to say that the handling of the language is a bit uncertain not with used with precision? In Swedish you can say (translated literally): your wording/structures - are phrased in an uncertain way.

Would a native speker use any of theses expressions: *shaky, cumbersome,ungainly, akward ....... or.....

Comment: What's the purpose of declaring a question a duplicate of another "not answerable" question? Why not just close it as "not constructive" as done in another case.

Comment: *shaky* (by itself, not with *structure*) is acceptable and is probably less 'judgmental' / more polite that your other suggestions.

Comment: My father marked freshman composition papers with *AWK* (for 'awkward'). I believe this was standard practice among professors of English -- I, of course, never saw this mark on my papers! :) (Well, hardly ever)